# Cannot foreach over an array of objects in a Laravel POST

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an array of objects which have been posted from a Vue Axios function, which I wish to loop over and save into a database. They are answers to a question.

I have passed in `$data` which is the array of answer objects (each has a content, correct and mark property), and the `$id` of the question they belong to. When I return `$data,` it shows me the array of objects with all the correct properties. When I return `$data[0]`, I can access the first object. But when I try and foreach as below, it complains that `$content` doesn't exist. Running `count()` on `$data` also errors. What is wrong here?

```php
Route::post('answers/{id}', function (Request $data, $id) {
    foreach ($data as $value) {
        $post[] = [
            'user_id' => 1,
            'question_id' => $id,
            'content' => $value->content,
            'correct' => $value->correct,
            'mark' => $value->mark
        ]);
    }

    Answer::save($post);
});
```

Comment: Is $value an object or an array?

Comment: $value should be an object but if I return it, it's an empty object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to iterate over the hole `$request` object, which is an instance of the [Request](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Http/Request.html) class. To access the received values first get them:

```php
// To get all the data
$data = $request->all();
// or..
// To get just a specific value
$data = $request->get('key');
// or..
// only a list of allowed elements
$data = $request->only('here', 'goes', 'your', 'keys');
```

So, in case your frontend are sending an array of items under the key `items`. Just get them like mentioned above:

```php
$items = $request->get('items');
```

Then you can use the `foreach()`:

```php
$items = $request->get('items');

foreach($items as $item)
{
    // your operations
}
```

---

You can read more about [Retrieving Input](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#retrieving-input), in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#retrieving-input).

Comment: Thanks! I can now run `count()` on `$items`, but when I try and access `$item->content`, I get "Trying to get property 'content' of non-object".

Comment: @ChrisWickham it'd be useful if you `dd($request->all());` to see what are you receiving.

Comment: Btw, that error can happen when you are trying to handle it as an object instead of an array. Try it again like this: `$item['content']`